# Detecting and Forecasting Intermittent Time Series

Tags: machine-learning, python, forecasting, inference, prophet

I am building a model to forecast some metrics. Those metrics are quite seasonal giving me good forecasts as shown below:

[image]

However, some new requirements dictate that I target those forecasts per groups. Those group can be per country, per company, etc. As you guessed, not all subgroups are able to be forecasted. Some look like the follow:

[image]

How can I identify those cases (I know there are tests, autocorrelation coefficient, etc) and most importantly how can I handle them?
For my usecase I am only interested to check the actual values against the limits (so anomaly detection).
If there are cases that modeling makes no sense, it is ok to say 'This subgroup cannot be modeled'

Answer (score 1):

For intermittent time series, you can use Croston's method. I personally never came across a situation where I had to use Croston's method however it is known to be an effective method to forecast time series with intermittent pattern.

Here is a link below for more information:
https://towardsdatascience.com/croston-forecast-model-for-intermittent-demand-360287a17f5f

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent 
repository of high-quality statistical information in the 
form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
link-only answers, due to link rot. Can you [edit] to include a full 
citation & a summary of the 
information at the link, in case it goes dead?